# Using the fact that 15° is half of 30°. Find the value of 15° and cos 15°.

Tags: trigonometry

Using the fact that 15° is half of 30°. Find the value of 15° and cos 15°.

Attempt: 
For cos 15°. I'm thinking I will do something like cos 45 - cos15. Get the values and replace it. Is that right? I'm not sure on how to go about the value of 15°

Comment: The value of 15 degrees is $\frac{\pi}{24}$ radians. For the cosine, use the half-angle or double-angle formula.

Comment: As a good practice, try to use the definition and draw a triangle, then derive the result from the diagram to ensure the result you get Algebraically.

Answer (score 2):

$$\cos2A=2\cos^2A-1\implies\cos^2A=\dfrac{1+\cos2A}2$$

Now if $A=15^\circ, \cos A>0$